# LinQ to Sql project with stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to make my first LINQ with asp website so I built a database with one table and I made a stored procedure which selects from this table by the `id` here it is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE select_article_by_id
@artcileid int
AS
    select * from articles where artcileid=@artcileid
    RETURN
```

then I dragged and droped it into my `DataClasses.dbml`
when I run the website this problem appear

```
An invalid data source is being used for articleDL.
A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.
```

and gives me this sorce Error :

```
Line 16:  string art_id = Request.QueryString["art_id"];
Line 17:  if (art_id != null)
Line 18:  articleDL.DataSource = DS.select_article_by_id(int.Parse(art_id)).Single();
Line 19:  
Line 20:  else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the data source accordingly:

```
articleDL.DataSource = DS.select_article_by_id(int.Parse(art_id)).Single();
```

By using `.Single()`, you are taking the one and only record returned by `select_article_by_id` and trying to make that single record the data source. It's telling you that's not allowed.

A list implements IEnumerable, which it's telling you *is* allowed. A single record does not implement IEnumerable, which it's telling you is *not* allowed.

Try replacing `.Single()` with `.ToList()`.

Comment: the error didn't appear ... but there is no result as well ! just a blank page

Comment: the article datalist didn't display any records !!

Comment: aha ...it worked already ... another error appeared ... but the main error was fixed thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE select_article_by_id
@artcileid int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  --<-- to suppress the message like "(100 row(s) affected)" 

     select * from articles where artcileid=@artcileid
END
```

Also you dont need the return key word here.